# Revert to an old version of an object in a versioned bucket

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

As part of https://github.com/wlandau/gittargets/issues/6, I am trying to programmatically revert an object in an S3 bucket to an earlier version. From reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RestoringPreviousVersions.html, it looks like copying the object to itself (old version to current version) is the most efficient way to go. But I do not know how to use HTTP/REST headers, and I do not know how to select the old version of the object. Is there a header I can specify or a request I can submit to make this work in R with `aws.s3`?

```r
library(aws.s3)
library(uuid)
bucket <- UUIDgenerate()
put_bucket(bucket)
#> [1] TRUE
put_versioning(bucket, "Enabled")
#> NULL
s3HTTP(
  verb = "GET",
  bucket = bucket,
  query = list(versioning = "")
)[1]
#> [1] "Enabled"

# old version
tmp <- tempfile()
writeLines("old", tmp)
out <- put_object(
  file = tmp,
  object = "object",
  bucket = bucket
)
version_old <- get_versions(bucket)$Version$VersionId

# new version
tmp <- tempfile()
writeLines("new", tmp)
out <- put_object(
  file = tmp,
  object = "object",
  bucket = bucket
)
version_new <- get_versions(bucket)$Version$VersionId

# Should be "new".
get_object("object", bucket, as = "text")
#> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
#> [1] "new\n"

# Should be "old". Why is it "new"?
get_object(
  "object",
  bucket,
  as = "text",
  headers = list(versionId = version_old)
)
#> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
#> [1] "new\n"

# Is this how I revert to the old version?
out <- copy_object(
  from_object = "object",
  to_object = "object",
  from_bucket = bucket,
  to_bucket = bucket,
  headers = list(versionId = version_old)
)
#> List of 4
#>  $ Code     : chr "InvalidRequest"
#>  $ Message  : chr "This copy request is illegal because it is trying to copy an object to itself without changing the object's met"| __truncated__
#>  $ RequestId: chr "JNVJ3H7B0B1KDFB3"
#>  $ HostId   : chr "Slte9SnTL0Xralznix6k93ez0Ja/8ij+pIqEMZmvq0zmfFPUdeFXWewWh80Ky/kViQ1ZhlVh44U="
#>  - attr(*, "headers")=List of 7
#>   ..$ x-amz-request-id : chr "JNVJ3H7B0B1KDFB3"
#>   ..$ x-amz-id-2       : chr "Slte9SnTL0Xralznix6k93ez0Ja/8ij+pIqEMZmvq0zmfFPUdeFXWewWh80Ky/kViQ1ZhlVh44U="
#>   ..$ content-type     : chr "application/xml"
#>   ..$ transfer-encoding: chr "chunked"
#>   ..$ date             : chr "Mon, 22 Nov 2021 19:13:59 GMT"
#>   ..$ server           : chr "AmazonS3"
#>   ..$ connection       : chr "close"
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "aws_error"
#>  - attr(*, "request_canonical")= chr "PUT\n/66553a84-0282-4ab8-87a5-e37a09aafcff/object\n\nhost:s3.amazonaws.com\nversionid:so6dk_b_t7CcEcbjj3Ok14sP4"| __truncated__
#>  - attr(*, "request_string_to_sign")= chr "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20211122T191359Z\n20211122/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\n8788609957ebcf0ab01338ed90ca4cd74e41747"| __truncated__
#>  - attr(*, "request_signature")= chr "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIA5IZZ3SMAULVNHKWK/20211122/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;versioni"| __truncated__
#> NULL
#> Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose): Bad Request (HTTP 400).
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info    ️  ‍   ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  hash: flag: San Marino, world map, man farmer: dark skin tone
#> 
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#>  os       macOS Big Sur 10.16
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       America/New_York
#>  date     2021-11-22
#>  pandoc   2.11.4 @ /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package       * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  aws.s3        * 0.3.22  2021-11-03 [1] Github (cloudyr/aws.s3@621e0ad)
#>  aws.signature   0.6.0   2020-06-01 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  backports       1.3.0   2021-10-27 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  base64enc       0.1-3   2015-07-28 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  cli             3.1.0   2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  crayon          1.4.2   2021-10-29 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  curl            4.3.2   2021-06-23 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  digest          0.6.28  2021-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  ellipsis        0.3.2   2021-04-29 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  evaluate        0.14    2019-05-28 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  fansi           0.5.0   2021-05-25 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  fastmap         1.1.0   2021-01-25 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  fs              1.5.0   2020-07-31 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  glue            1.5.0   2021-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  highr           0.9     2021-04-16 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  htmltools       0.5.2   2021-08-25 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  httr            1.4.2   2020-07-20 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  knitr           1.36    2021-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  lifecycle       1.0.1   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  magrittr        2.0.1   2020-11-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  mime            0.12    2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  pillar          1.6.4   2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  pkgconfig       2.0.3   2019-09-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  purrr           0.3.4   2020-04-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.cache         0.15.0  2021-04-30 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.methodsS3     1.8.1   2020-08-26 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.oo            1.24.0  2020-08-26 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R.utils         2.11.0  2021-09-26 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  R6              2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  reprex          2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rlang           0.4.12  2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rmarkdown       2.11    2021-09-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rstudioapi      0.13    2020-11-12 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  sessioninfo     1.2.1   2021-11-02 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  stringi         1.7.5   2021-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  stringr         1.4.0   2019-02-10 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  styler          1.6.2   2021-09-23 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  tibble          3.1.6   2021-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  utf8            1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  uuid          * 1.0-3   2021-11-01 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  vctrs           0.3.8   2021-04-29 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  withr           2.4.2   2021-04-18 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  xfun            0.28    2021-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  xml2            1.3.2   2020-04-23 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  yaml            2.2.1   2020-02-01 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /Users/c240390/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library
#>  [2] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to use [paws: AWS SDK for r](https://github.com/paws-r/paws) to call AWS. See: [An Amazon SDK for R!? | R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/10/an-amazon-sdk-for-r/)

Comment: Yup, {paws} is also on my radar, and I am having similar problems: https://github.com/paws-r/paws/issues/471. Would be nice to avoid {botor} because of the Python dependency.